# What "aggregate-oriented domain" means (speaking of a Spring-based application)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

From [spring-framework-petclinic](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-framework-petclinic)

> [this](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-framework-petclinic) repo is a fork of the [spring-projects/spring-petclinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic). It allows
>   the Spring community to maintain a Petclinic version with a plain old
>   Spring Framework configuration and with a *3-layer architecture (i.e.
>   presentation --> service --> repository)*. The "[canonical](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic)"
>   implementation is now based on Spring Boot, Thymeleaf and
>   **aggregate-oriented domain**.

I googled a lot, but the term "aggregate-oriented domain" cannot be googled successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means its domain model uses the Aggregate pattern from Domain-Driven Design.

See:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/pull/200
- https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AggregateOrientedDatabase.html